# Extra argument in call when appending data to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a custom table cell which takes an image and some few strings. Now I make an async call to get some JSON which works fine. After getting my JSON I'm trying to append it to my array but I get Extra argument in call. Below is my sample code:

//Struct for array details

```
struct CellData {
    let image: UIImage?
    let name: String?
    let distance: String?
    let desc: String?
}
var locationData = [CellData]()
//Then in my background thread

let responseMessage = parseJSON["RESPONSEMESSAGE"] as! NSArray?
if let array = responseMessage {
    for obj in array{
        if let dict = obj as? NSDictionary {
            let shopName = dict.value(forKey: "NAME") as? String
            let shopLandMark = dict.value(forKey: "LANDMARK") as! String?
            var shopDistance = dict.value(forKey: "DISTANCE") as! String?
            shopDistance = "\(shopDistance) km"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.locationData.append(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "wifi"), shopName!, shopDistance!, shopLandMark!) //Error on this line (Extra argument in call)
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your append takes only one argument - an instance of type `CellData`.

You need to create an **instance** of the type `CellData` and append that instance to the array.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    for obj in array{
        if let dict = obj as? [String: String] {
            if let shopName = dict["NAME"] as? String, let shopLandMark = dict.["LANDMARK"] as? String?, let shopDistance = dict["DISTANCE"] as? String? {
                let shopLocation = CellData(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "wifi"), name: shopName, distance: shopDistance, desc: shopLandMark)
                locationData.append(shopLocation)
            }
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If your response API changes and your keys do not give you values, your app will crash. So safely unwrap your values and use them. Avoid using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. Use `Array` and `Dictionary` instead.

Comment: **Also you don't need to do this on the main thread.** Swift `Array` is not thread safe. An Array which may be referenced or modified in the main thread should be updated in the main thread.

Comment: Error is no more but my table is not populated

Comment: @chevi99 probably because it is not on the main thread like OOPer said. try it on the main thread like how you have it. Also you should reload the table afterwards. Hope you did not forget that part.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, problems caused by this fact rarely happens, so it can be a hard-to-debug issue. By the way, if `locationData` is used as a dataSource, there should be `tableView.reloadData()` after for-in statement.

Comment: @OOPer Yes, but since there is an async block inside the loop. Where do i add it? Seems to me like i there should be a `DispatchGroup`? ( I know there are no time consuming operation on the UI thread but just to be safe? Or will it never fail? )

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, I would enclose whole for-in loop into a closure of `DispatchQueue.main.async`, as well as `tableView.reloadData()`. (Of, course, removing all inner `DispatchQueue.main.async`.) Inside the for-in loop of the OP, there are no asynchronous methods.

Comment: @OOPer yea i probably overthought it. :x _whoops_

Comment: Shared data is the _most_ dangerous time for multithreading. Telling the questioner not to worry about what thread he appends to an instance property on is a _terrible_ thing to do.

Comment: @matt yea. Sorry, i forgot to take down that part after editing the code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thanks. your edit worked fine. But the only issue is when I replaced NSDictionary with Dictionary I got an error.

Comment: @chevi99 sorry about that. Edited again. Check if this works. You should probably be using `JSONSerialization` to get dictionaries for JSON data.